# Conservative $\text{Ho}\mathcal{V}$-functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\mathcal{V}$-model category.

> Which hypotheses on  $\mathcal{M}$ guarantee the existence of a conservative $\text{Ho}\mathcal{V}$-functor $$\text{Ho}\mathcal{M} \to \text{Ho}\mathcal{V} ?$$

- By $\mathcal{V}$-model category I mean what Shulman means [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610194.pdf).
- By conservative  $\mathcal{W}$-functor between $\mathcal{W}$-categories I mean that the functor between their underlining categories is conservative .

In these days I have the feeling that a $\mathcal{W}$-category $\mathcal{K}$ has very often a conservative $\mathcal{W}$-functor: $$\mathcal{K} \to  \mathcal{W}, $$
this feeling motivates my question.